# reading multiple files python . Im able to read a single text and encrypt it

Tags: python, python-3.x

With the code below i'm able to encrypt a single file and decrypt it to the specified location. Now i wants to read multiple file as input and decrypt it to the destination. How can I achieve it.

```
import os
dd = {'A': ')', 'a': '0', 'B': '(', 'b': '9', 'C': '*', 'c': '8',
    'D': '&', 'd': '7', 'E': '^', 'e': '6', 'F': '%', 'f': '5',
    'G': '$', 'g': '4', 'H': '#', 'h': '3', 'I': '@', 'i': '2',
    'J': '!', 'j': '1', 'K': 'Z', 'k': 'z', 'L': 'Y', 'l': 'y',
    'M': 'X', 'm': 'x', 'N': 'W', 'n': 'w', 'O': 'V', 'o': 'v',
    'P': 'U', 'p': 'u', 'Q': 'T', 'q': 't', 'R': 'S', 'r': 's',
    'S': 'R', 's': 'r', 'T': 'Q', 't': 'q', 'U': 'P', 'u': 'p',
    'V': 'O', 'v': 'o', 'W': 'N', 'w': 'n', 'X': 'M', 'x': 'm',
    'Y': 'L', 'y': 'l', 'Z': 'K', 'z': 'k', '!': 'J', '1': 'j',
    '@': 'I', '2': 'i', '#': 'H', '3': 'h', '$': 'G', '4': 'g',
    '%': 'F', '5': 'f', '^': 'E', '6': 'e', '&': 'D', '7': 'd',
    '*': 'C', '8': 'c', '(': 'B', '9': 'b', ')': 'A', '0': 'a',
    ':': ',', ',': ':', '?': '.', '.': '?', '<': '>', '>': '<',
    "'": '"', '"': "'", '+': '-', '-': '+', '=': ';', ';': '=',
    '{': '[', '[': '{', '}': ']', ']': '}'}

def encryption():
    infile = str(input('Enter the name of the input file: '))
    dtext = open(infile, 'r')
    dtext = dtext.readlines()
    encryptText(dtext)

def encryptText(dtext):
    outfile = str(input('Enter the name of the output file: '))
    etext = open(outfile, 'w')
    for line in dtext:
        for cword in line:
            encrypted = (dd.get(cword, cword))
            etext.write(encrypted)
    etext.close()
encryption()
```

Many thanks advance

Comment: Use a loop around the call to `encryption`? Asking people to write the new code from scratch is frowned upon. Try to write it yourself, ask a question (with a [MCVE]) if you have a problem. As is, "do it for multiple files" is incredibly broad (how many times? Do you still get names from `input()`, or are you going to make this useful programmatically by passing around `list`s of names?)

Comment: It's for my practice. yes if you provide input as text file it will encrypt according to the dictionary keys above. I'm looking to provide the input as path and it should have multiple text files and ecrypt it and write it to outfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ShadowRanger pointed out, it's unclear what you are trying to achieve.

But generally for working with multiple files, you can use `glog.glob` function and just provide a mask for it as an input.

For example, here's a slightly modified code of yours which uses glob:

```
import os, glob

dd = {'A': ')', 'a': '0', 'B': '(', 'b': '9', 'C': '*', 'c': '8',
    'D': '&', 'd': '7', 'E': '^', 'e': '6', 'F': '%', 'f': '5',
    'G': '$', 'g': '4', 'H': '#', 'h': '3', 'I': '@', 'i': '2',
    'J': '!', 'j': '1', 'K': 'Z', 'k': 'z', 'L': 'Y', 'l': 'y',
    'M': 'X', 'm': 'x', 'N': 'W', 'n': 'w', 'O': 'V', 'o': 'v',
    'P': 'U', 'p': 'u', 'Q': 'T', 'q': 't', 'R': 'S', 'r': 's',
    'S': 'R', 's': 'r', 'T': 'Q', 't': 'q', 'U': 'P', 'u': 'p',
    'V': 'O', 'v': 'o', 'W': 'N', 'w': 'n', 'X': 'M', 'x': 'm',
    'Y': 'L', 'y': 'l', 'Z': 'K', 'z': 'k', '!': 'J', '1': 'j',
    '@': 'I', '2': 'i', '#': 'H', '3': 'h', '$': 'G', '4': 'g',
    '%': 'F', '5': 'f', '^': 'E', '6': 'e', '&': 'D', '7': 'd',
    '*': 'C', '8': 'c', '(': 'B', '9': 'b', ')': 'A', '0': 'a',
    ':': ',', ',': ':', '?': '.', '.': '?', '<': '>', '>': '<',
    "'": '"', '"': "'", '+': '-', '-': '+', '=': ';', ';': '=',
    '{': '[', '[': '{', '}': ']', ']': '}'}

def encryption(infile):
    dtext = open(infile, 'r')
    dtext = dtext.readlines()
    print ('Input filename: ' + infile)

    # this was your encryptText(dtext) function
    outfile = raw_input('Enter the name of the output file: ')
    etext = open(outfile, 'w')
    for line in dtext:
        for cword in line:
            encrypted = (dd.get(cword, cword))
            etext.write(encrypted)
    etext.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
    mask = raw_input('Enter the mask for input files: ')
    for filename in glob.glob(mask):
        encryption(filename)
```

To encode all the .txt files, you would type *.txt:

```
Enter the mask for input files: *.txt
```

And then it will ask you for the output file names.

(Note that I incorporated your encryptText() function into the encryption() function. There is no need for two functions now.)